# Cannot connect to windows share on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, samba, shared-folders

I'm currently using ubuntu 15.10 and trying to use the 'recommended' way of connecting to a share by going to Files -> Connect to server.

I can get to the password prompt since the share is password protected, but when I fill out the information, but when I do it the window comes back with like 90% of it greyed out, and this shows up in /var/log/syslog:

```
Feb  8 16:42:21 ubuntu org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1060]: ### SMB: do_mount - [smb://[ip/share]; 1] res = -1, cancelled = 0, errno = [1] 'Operation not permitted'
```

After doing some research apparently the way to fix this is to enable a guest account on the windows share, but I can't do that because the server with the shares are connected to an open college network, and as a result it would be very unsafe to open a guest account on the windows machine for the share.

Is there any way to fix this?